# PVLIB - How to properly define system size with couple inverters

Tags: python, pvlib

I'm trying to model a system with 5 inverters but there is no parameter for PVSystem object that takes number of inverters, only modules per string and strings per inverter (but still it assumes that there is only one inverter). Also there is no argument for power installed which would allow to skip sizing details.

For large PV plants it is crucial as for example there would be ~50 000 PV modules and they can't just be connected to only one inverter.

How could I properly set it up so I can do further calculations?

[PVSystem attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg4CL.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 2020-06-21, you can only simulate a system with multiple inverters "manually". That means, you need to calculate the topology yourself:

- Number of required inverters
- Strings per inverter (and modules per string)

Then you can simulate each inverter separately.

Hopefully, this will change in the future. :-D

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays are the same you don't need to make complex your code. just run it for one array and multiply the results by 5.
if they are different in orientation, you should import them one by one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).